# adding to javascript multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I want the following structure:

```
    {
     "1":[
        {"name":"John","Age":"21"}
      ]
     "2":[
        {"name":"Jone","Age":"22"}
      ]
    }
```

I want to dynamically add objects.This is what I tried:

```
    var i = 0;
    var data= [{i:{}}]; 
    function add(){
      data= [{i:{}}];
      data.i.push({
        "name":"Zack",
        "age":22
      });
      i++;
    }
```

I got an error "**Cannot call method 'push' of undefined**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To access a property dynamically, use the bracket notation. `data= [{i:{}}]` doesn't do what you want, it doesn't use the fact you just defined the `i` variable.
2. In your function, you're replacing the external value of `data`.

What you want is probably much simpler :

```
var i = 0;
var data= {};
function add(){
  data[i] = data[i]||[];
  data[i].push({
    "name":"Zack",
    "age":22
  });
  i++;
}
```

More details in this MDN documentation : [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Looks like he wrapped his object in an array. data[0].i?

Comment: data[i++].push ... one less line :)

Comment: var data={}; worked!But like Raibaz said,data[i] is not an array so .push didnt work.Using data[i] = {"name": "Raibaz", "age": 30} worked.

Comment: @phpcoderx using directly data[i] = your object doesn't build the same structure than the one you showed. Note that I updated the code with data[i] = data[i]||[] to ensure data[i] is an array and is initialized.

Comment: Sorry,didn't see your edit.And btw is there a way to read the name using i as index? I tried alert(data[i].name); .But it gave me an error"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined "

Comment: If you use the structure of your question, then it would be `data[i][0].name`.

Comment: You're probably reading for a value of `i` for which there's no array. If that may happen, you'll have to test `if (data[i])` before trying to read `data[i][0]`

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `data` as `[{i:{}}]`, the structure you are obtaining is actually

```
[
    {
        i: {
        }
    }
]
```

Which is not the one you wanted, and the reason why you can't access `data.i` (since `data` is an array).

You should declare `data` as `{i:{}}` and then access `i` with the bracket notation, as `data[i]`.

Besides, since `data[i]` is not an array, `.push` won't work either, so you should use something like `data[i] = {"name": "Raibaz", "age": 30}`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript multi dimensional arrays are created by using following syntax

```
var mArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]];
```

and

```
mArray[0][0] gives 1
mArray[0][1] gives 2
mArray[1][0] gives 3
mArray[1][1] gives 4
```

You can initialize your multidimensional array as given below

```
var i = 0;
var data= [];
```

What you are trying to create is an object of arrays. In that case syntax is (as in your code)

```
var mObject = {
 "1":[
    {"name":"John","Age":"21"}
  ]
 "2":[
    {"name":"Jone","Age":"22"}
  ]
};
```

You can initialize your object as given below

```
var i = 1;
var data= {};
```

And in both cases the function can be written as given below

```
function add(){
  data[i] = data[i] || []; // initializes array if it is undefined
  data[i].push({
    "name":"Zack",
    "age":22
  });
  i++;
}
```